# Function added to .bashrc doesn't work

Tags: bash, function, elementary-os

I've added this function to my .bashrc file:

```
SSH(){
    ssh -X -o PasswordAuthentication=yes root@10.222.22.$*
}
```

and while trying to perform for ex. `SSH 101` I get message:

```
SSH: command not found
```

Comment: .bashrc is read once you log in or spawn a new shell. Alternatively issue `. ~/.bashrc` to re-read it.

Comment: But it happens even after rebooting.

Comment: What does `type SSH` output?

Comment: @Costas You mean typing `SSH` without argument? Also `SSH: command not found`.

Comment: I mean command `type` with argument `SSH`

Comment: In the case there is no reason to use *function* instead ordinary *alias*

Comment: @Costas After typing `type SSH`: `bash: type: SSH: not found`. Can I assign parameter to alias? I thought it is not possible.

Comment: Try to `grep -lx SSH $(locate .bashrc)`

Comment: @Costas Terminal has been refreshed and nothing else happened.

Comment: So this mean: there is not *SSH function* in your *bashrc*-files

Comment: Sorry, it should be `grep -lw SSH $(locate .bashrc)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bash as your login shell?
 `ps aux | grep $$`

Some Linux Distros or UNIXes may not source ~/.bashrc but ~/.bash_profile. You could add
`source ~/.bashrc` to your ~/.profile

Alternatively you could use `~/.ssh/config` to add special settings for certain hosts, like this:

```
Host ? ?? ???
    User root
    HostName 10.222.22.%h
    PasswordAuthentication=yes
    ForwardX11=yes
```

And `ssh 101` should do the same like your function `SSH 101`.

Comment: I've tried it both on root/normal user.